# No module named flask.ext.wtf when building with py2exe

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, flask-wtforms

On a Windows 8.1 machine with Python 2.7, I try to make a flask-script executable using py2exe. The script itself runs perfectly, but not so the compiled .exe.

This is `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['app.py'],
    options={
           'py2exe': {'includes': ['flask']}
           }
    )
```

Starting `app.exe` from the command, I get an `ImportError: no module named flask.ext.wtf`.

I then tried including `flask-WTF` (i.e. change the line to `'py2exe': {'includes': ['flask-wtf', 'flask-wtf']}`). But while building, I get another `ImportError: no module named flask-WTF` - although this is the name I used to install it! So how can I make my `app.exe` work properly?

Comment: I think it's ```distutils``` related question. You have to add install_requires=['flask-wth==x.y.z'] if flask-WTF is external dependency.

Comment: @VladimirIgnatyev: I added `add install_requires=['flask-wtf==x.y.z']` in my setup.py before the options parameter. However, nothing changed (I think the line was simply ignored). So where should I add the parameter and what does `x.y.z` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that the module is named `flask_wtf` (with an underscore).

Hence the following `setup.py` worked:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['app.py'],
    options={
           'py2exe': {'includes': ['flask', 'flask_wtf']}
           }
    )
```